# How to use xslt to calculate average and display results in a table

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am taking an xml class.  I am a beginner and I am trying to learn xslt 1.0.

I am trying to figure out how I can calculate the average per student and make the result show in a table for the right student. For now, the average calculation is incorrect and I don't know how I can get the average to show in another column beside the name.  Please keep your answer simple as I am a beginner.  Thank you !

The result should look like this :

```
Student        Average
Jeff Cooper     70.0
Laureen Hanley  95.0
Peter Manning   74.3
Robert Shaw     78.7
```

This is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="temptransfo.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<university>
<student><name>Robert Shaw</name>
<course code="INF4830" note="90" />
<course code="INF1130" note="70" />
<course code="INF1330" note="76" /></student>
<student><name>Peter Manning</name>
<course code="INF4830" note="76" />
<course code="INF1130" note="73" />
<course code="INF1330" note="74" /></student>
<student><name>Jeff Cooper</name>
<course code="INF4930" note="40" />
<course code="INF1130" note="90" />
<course code="INF1330" note="80" /></student>
<student><name>Laureen Hanley</name>
<course code="INF4830" note="92" />
<course code="INF1330" note="98" /></student>
</university>
```

And this is so far what I've done in my xsl file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output 
    method="html"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    indent="yes" ></xsl:output>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Exercice 1</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table border ="1">
    <caption>Exercice 1</caption>
    <tr>
    <th>Student</th>
    <th>Average</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="university/student" >
    <xsl:sort select="substring-after(name,' ')" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    </table>

</body>
</html>         
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="student"> 
    <tr>
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number((sum(preceding::course/@note) div count (preceding::course)),'##.0')"/> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, you have confused yourself by working with an improperly indented XML input. Otherwise you would have seen that `course` is a **child** of `student`, and the average can be computed simply as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(course/@note) div count(course),'#.0')"/>
```

Comment: And how do I do to make the average show in a another column beside the right student name ?

Comment: You have all that working already. Just change your calculation to mine.

Comment: Got it !!!! You were right ! I got confused with the indent ! Everything works fine now ! Thank you so much ! :-)

Comment: Hi Michael,  I am now trying to do something a little bit different but with the same xml file.  I updated my post with the new information.  I don't know if what I did is ok or if there would have been an easier way to obtain this result but now my average does not return good results ... :-(

Comment: I have rolled back your question to what it was when I answered it. Please post a new question with your new, entirely different, problem. Also study http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html before you do.

Comment: Thank you Michael !